# d3.js make axis ticks clickable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to make the labels on the axis clickable. Right now my axis are generated as follows:

```
    // Add an x-axis with label.
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "xaxis")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + margin.left_padding) + "," + height + ")")
        .attr("text_anchor", "top")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"))
        .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("font-size", "12")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-45)"
            })


    // Add a y-axis with label.
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "yaxis")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left + margin.left_padding) + "," + 0 + ")")
        .attr("text-anchor", "right")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"))
        .selectAll("text")
           .attr("font-size", "12")

    }
```

I'm wondering how to make it possible for each number/label on the axis have an onclick event.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can select them with d3 and then bind a function to them with `.on('click', function)`

For your code, this would look something like this:

```
d3.select('#xaxis')
    .selectAll('.tick.major')
    .on('click',clickMe)

function clickMe(){alert("I've been clicked!")}
```

Note that this will select the entire tick, not just the text, since `.tick.major` is the class of the group that contains both the tick label (the text) and the tick itself (an SVG line).

You can also use `d` as an argument in the function you are calling on your ticks. If you do so, `d` will contain the value of the tick. For example, the following would send an alert containing each tick value:

```
d3.select('#xaxis')
    .selectAll('.tick.major')
    .on('click',clickMe)

function clickMe(d){alert(d)}
```

Note that you can probably call `.major` instead of `.tick.major` if nothing but the major ticks has the `major` class.

Comment: This looks great! I'll let you know if I have any problems with the implementation. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the click event might only register once? I click one of the ticks and it does the clickme function but when I click other ticks nothing happens.

Comment: Hard to say without being able to see your code. I'd recommend putting the most basic click event you can on them and test from there.

Comment: Alright, I'll work through it. Your example worked perfectly fine so definitely thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Is there way to make the clickable area larger than the visible tick? my strokewidths are 2px but it's almost impossible to click

Comment: @Boyen You can append a rect element with opacity 0 to each tick and use that for your click target.